# Implementation of instance and class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, namespaces

I'm curious about the implementation of Python's class and instance variables. I can't find an answer in the docs and, to be frank, I don't particularly want to wade through all of the Python source code.

The properties of these can be summarized as follows:

- altering a class variable alters this attribute for all class instances
- altering an instance variable overrides the class variables

This is demonstrated below

```
>>> class cA:
...     pub = "public"
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.priv = "private"
... 
>>> aI = cA()
>>> bI = cA()
>>> aI.pub; bI.pub
'public'
'public'
>>> cA.pub = "public2"
>>> aI.pub; bI.pub
'public2'
'public2'
>>> aI.pub = "public3"
>>> aI.pub; bI.pub
'public3'
'public2'
>>> # Oh no!
```

My question is: how is this accomplished (what are the relevant implementation details)?

Below is my hypothesis and reasoning.

---

Restarting everything and examining the instance's namespaces, it would appear that they each contain a direct reference to the object `pub`, and examination of memory location informs us they do indeed point to the same object:

```
>>> aI = cA()
>>> bI = cA()
>>> dir(aI)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'priv', **'pub'**]
>>> dir(bI)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'priv', **'pub'**]
>>> id(aI.pub); id(bI.pub)
4466990384
4466990384
```

Examining the namespace of the class itself, we see `pub` here as well:

If `aI` and `bI` did indeed contain direct references to the object then any alteration to this object (creation of a new one) would have to place the new object in the same location for aI.pub to resolve properly. However, we see this is not the case:

```
>>> id(cA.pub)
4466990384
>>> cA.pub = "public2 I'm making this longer to avoid interning effects"
>>> id(cA.pub)
4467260752
>>> id(aI.pub); id(bI.pub)
4467260752
4467260752
```

Now, since we haven't modified any of `aI`'s memory we can only assume that `pub` does not, despite what `dir` above implies, actually contain a reference to the class variable `pub`.

My hypothesis (please confirm/deny) is that the instances don't contain anything actually connecting them to the class variable, that there is a class dict and then a dict for each instance, and that what happens when a class variable is accessed is that local resolution fails, it goes up the hierarchy (next in line which is the class dict) which then resolves the reference and access the object (ref to class → ref to object → object) i.e.

```
cADict = {reference to pub object}

aIDict = {reference to priv object, to class}
```

(the alternative, that `aI` actually **does** contain a direct reference to the pub object, would require that every time a class instance is updated it would have to iterate through all instances of that class and update their pub reference - which is not practical)

A follow up to my original: seeing as `pub` isn't actually in `aI`'s namespace, why does `dir()` say that it is?

(I thought that `dir` prints a list of all references in an object's namespace?)

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking (it's not very clear), the answer might be "yes".

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry about that. I edited it - hopefully it's clearer what I'm asking now.